# How can i get active ios device or simulator UDID?

Tags: java, iphone, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

I can get all available devices by "instruments -s device"

I am not able to identify which one is active device. How can i identify active device or simulator programmatically in JAVA.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi,
Here is the solution if anyone looking for similar problem.    


`processUDID = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("xcrun simctl list devices");    
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
     processUDID.getInputStream()));
   Stream<String> stream = in.lines();
   stream.forEach(s -> {

    if (s.contains("Booted")) {
     String ud = deviceUdid = s.substring(s.indexOf("-") - 8)
       .trim();

     ud = deviceUdid = ud.substring(0, ud.indexOf(")")).trim();

     simulatorUdid = ud;

    }

   });`

Comment: but this doesn't give UDID of the physical device but only the simulator

Answer (score 5):

```
$ xcrun simctl list devices | grep 'Booted'
iPhone 5 (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX) (Booted)
```

Comment: this doesn't show connected physical device but only shows iOS simulator

Answer (score 3):

This is not done programmatically in JAVA as originally asked, but might help someone.

To get all **active iOS physical devices** and iOS simulators with their UDIDs:

```
$ xcrun xctrace list devices
```

To find the **active iOS simulator** with its UDID:

```
$ xcrun simctl list | grep Booted
```